# multipart http request to upload images

Tags: blackberry, post, java-me, upload, multipart

I m trying to use multipart post request to upload two string parameters( token and source) and an image captured from mobile device ( return jpeg encoded byte[] ). But it is generating error which I am sure is due to incorrect request.

I am still not sure about notation on creating a multipart post request. So any helpful links and resources would be good.

The code is for Blackberry java development

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String boundary = "--@#$--";
byte[] image = byte[] from camera.getsnapshot;

buffer.append(boundary+"\r\nContent-Disposition: form-    data;name=\"token\"\r\n"+token+"\r\n");

buffer.append(boundary+"\r\nContent-Disposition: form-    data;name=\"source\"\r\n"+"Blackberry"+"\r\n");

buffer.append(boundary+"\r\nContent-Disposition: form-   data;name=\"file.jpg\";filename=\""+ "file.jpg"+"\""+"\n" +    "Content-   Type:image/jpeg"+"\n"+ "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + boundary +"\r\n" +new    String(image));
buffer.append("\r\n" + boundary + "\r\n");

String string = new String(buffer);

byte[] post = string.getBytes();



HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE,
HttpProtocolConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_FORM_DATA+
";boundary="+boundary);

    connection.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH,String.valueOf(post.length));     

connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP_2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
OutputStream postStream =connection.openOutputStream();
postStream.write(post,0,post.length);
postStream.close();
```

\----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this Nokia Community wiki page will help you: [HTTP Post multipart file upload in Java ME](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME)